# Como adicionar linhas de dados em uma coluna em SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, ssis

Estou importando dados da Rais (ME). O estado é o Acre. Eu criei duas colunas: **Uf1** e **Ano1**. Em **Uf1** vai a informação **AC** e em **Ano1** recebe a informação **2014**. Percebam que inserir, nas duas primeiras linhas, em Ano1, a informação 2014. Porém, esse banco de dados tem milhares de linhas o que impossibilita o uso do INSERT INTO ou da inserção manual pelo próprio editor do SQL Server (SSMS).

Sendo assim, como faço para inserir esses valores em todas as linhas? Obs.: são valores iguais. Ou seja, nas mais de 1.000 linhas de **Uf1** será a informação **AC**. Em **Ano1** será a informação **2014**.

Já emendo outra pergunta. É possível fazer isso através do SSIS do Microsoft Visual Studio?
Consegui criar as variáveis (colunas) **Uf1** e **Ano1** durante a importação, mas não consegui adicionar os dados pretendidos.

[image: Dados]

Comment: Vc quer extrair os dados ou atualizar a tabela? Não entendi direito

Comment: Se os registros já existem em seu banco de dados então você não deve utilizar `INSERT` e sim `UPDATE`. Se deseja o mesmo valor em todos os registros faça: `UPDATE sua_tabela SET Uf1 = 'AC', Ano1 = 2014;`.

Comment: Muito bom. Resolveu meu problema. Obrigado!!!!!!!!!!